# Div,show,hide toggle. with changing link Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey ,  I tried to make a hide/show toogle for my site. And change the link color.

I know the prob is the input.
The linkcolor goes on the divs. Not on the link.

Maybe anybody have an good idea.
Think i need a new function. (jquery is on) maybe a shorter way is possible.

Thanks in advance!

//javascipt

```
          function toggleMe(a){
      var e=document.getElementById(a);
      var col=document.getElementById(a);
      if(!e)return true;
      if(e.style.display=="none"){
        e.style.display="block"
        col.style.color="#000000"     
      } else {
        e.style.display="none"
     col.style.color="#000000"
      }
      return true;
    }

//input 

  <div id="topp">

        <div id="tops">

             <li> <a href="www.google" target="_self">Serien</a></li>
                 <li>Architektur</li>
              <li >Portrait</li>
              <li><a href=# onclick="return toggleMe('about')">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href=#  onclick="return toggleMe('kont')">Kontakt</a></li>
      <li><a href=#  onclick="return toggleMe('imp')">Impressum</a></li>
             <lie><span class="Stil1">Su</span>terrain.de</li></div>

                 </div>     
          </div>
//divs

         <div id="about" style="display:none" onclick="hideBox('about');">
    Lutz Bartelt<br />
    About

         </div>



         <div id="kont" style="display:none" onclick="hideBox('kont');">
    Lutz Bartelt<br />
 <br />
    01522386174<br />
    WhiteWall<br />



     </div>


         <div id="imp" style="display:none" onclick="hideBox('imp');">
    impress
     </div>
```

Comment: You can't have an `li` element as a direct descendant of another `li` element, it needs to be inside of an `ol` or `ul`, and the same is true of an `li` being a child of a `div`: it's **invalid**.

Comment: If you have jQuery why you don't use it? variables a and col are the same and you have the same color in if and else clause.

Comment: thx for fast response. dont think that the li ul think is the prob. jquery i would to use it but how. Sorry i have rly no plan from java:(

Comment: @user586797: you're right, I only think that *one* of your problems is the invalid html. I'm not quite sure what's going on with the JavaScript, but it seems ridiculously overly-complex given your use-case. I realise that jQuery can be over-simplified and abstracted, but if it's available to you, it's worth using just for the simplicity and abstraction. Not to mention the move away from the `onclick`-based click-handlers...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've adapted your html:

```
<div id="tops">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="www.google" target="_self">Serien</a></li>
        <li>Architektur</li>
        <li>Portrait</li>
        <li><a href="#" name="about">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="impressum">Impressum</a></li>
        <li><span class="Stil1">Su</span>terrain.de</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="panels">
    <div id="about">
        Lutz Bartelt<br />
        About
    </div>

    <div id="kontakt">
        Lutz Bartelt<br />
        <br />
        01522386174<br />
        WhiteWall<br />
    </div>

    <div id="impressum">
        impress
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery seems to do what I think you're trying to do:

```
$('#tops > ul > li > a').click(

function() {
    var showThis = $(this).attr('name');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#panels > div').hide();
    $('#' + showThis).show();
    return false;
});
```

I used an 'active' class-name for the color changing, which in the demo is defined in CSS as:

```
.active {
    color: #f00;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo of the above](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PSgJ2/1/).

Comment: wow nice thanx, this is what i want. but without the switch, meanyou aktivate all and deaktivete all by them self. But rly nice short CODE.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the link object so there was no way for you to actually change the color of it:

```
function toggleMe( div, link )
{
  var e = document.getElementById( div );
  if( !e ) return( true );
  if( e.style.display == "none" )
  {
    e.style.display = "block";
    link.style.color = "red";
  }
  else
  {
    e.style.display = "none";
    link.style.color = "blue";
  }
  return( false );
}

<div id="topp">

            <div id="tops">

                 <li> <a href="www.google" target="_self">Serien</a></li>
                     <li>Architektur</li>
                  <li >Portrait</li>
                  <li><a href=# onclick="return toggleMe('about', this)">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#  onclick="return toggleMe('kont', this)">Kontakt</a></li>
          <li><a href=#  onclick="return toggleMe('imp', this)">Impressum</a></li>
                 <lie><span class="Stil1">Su</span>terrain.de</li></div>

                     </div>     
              </div>
    //divs

             <div id="about" style="display:none" onclick="hideBox('about');">
        Lutz Bartelt<br />
        About

             </div>



             <div id="kont" style="display:none" onclick="hideBox('kont');">
        Lutz Bartelt<br />
     <br />
        01522386174<br />
        WhiteWall<br />



         </div>


             <div id="imp" style="display:none" onclick="hideBox('imp');">
        impress
         </div>
```

Edit: You may also want to return false at the bottom of the function so the URL isn't actually followed.

Comment: and this is exakt this what i want nice nice nice. Thx a lot

Comment: maybe is it possible to put .toggle("slow")  instad of style.display?

Comment: @user586797: It's customary here to accept an answer when it's exactly what you want.